# MVVM Multiple Bindings Problem

Tags: silverlight, binding, mvvm-light

I have the following XAML layout

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Reports">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="Edit" 
                               Command={Binding MyCommand} <!-- From View Model -->
                               CommandParameter={Binding Id}/> <!-- From DataTemplate -->
        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
```

I would like to bind a command to the button which would require me to set the data context of the button to the ViewModel.

But I would like to bind data from the DataTemplate data context to the command parameter.

Is is possible to have two data contexts within the same control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. But you can associate the binding to a command in your viewmodel:

```
<telerik:RadButton x:Name="Edit" 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, ElementName=Root}" <!-- From View Model -->
    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/> <!-- From DataTemplate -->
```

Here "Root" is the name of the user control or page where you are using this code:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root" ...
```

This page would be bound to your view model, so you can use the DataContext to access it. That's why you use the path `DataContext.MyCommand` in the binding.
Finally, in your viewmodel, you should have the command:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm struggling to understand exactly how to use the code you've posted, would you be able to elaborate on it a little bit please. Thanks.

Comment: I extended the answer a little bit. Let me know if it's clearer now :)